# ESLint: Assignment to property of function parameter 'element' (no-param-reassign)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

```
export const displayElement = (element) => element.style.display = 'block';
```

Error:

```
Assignment to property of function parameter 'element' (no-param-reassign).
```

This is a setting from the airbnb eslint. Thing is, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. What would be the recommended way to assign the style property?

Comment: What does no-param-reassign mean?

Comment: It's a setting on eslint that is saying that I'm trying to reassign a property on a function parameter.

Comment: Why would assigning or reassigning a property on a function parameter cause a warning?

Comment: @guest271314 It's considered a good practice not to mutate function parameters.

Comment: @Gothdo only in functional languages...

Comment: @Gothdo Do you mean that parameters passed to functions should not be overwritten or changed? Link to documentation describing the considerations and practices of handling function parameters?

Comment: @Alnitak JavaScript can be written in functional style.

Comment: @guest271314 Documentation doesn't say anything about it, because it's rather a matter of style. It isn't an official recommendation.

Comment: @Gothdo Where did you find a description of the style pattern recommending to not change function parameters?

Comment: @guest271314 https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--mutate-params

Comment: @Gothdo sure, it can, but unlike most real functional languages variables in JS *are* mutable, and setters are called implicitly (if required) when you set the value of a property, so there's usually no need for objects to expose explicit "obj.setSomeProperty(newValue)` calls.

Comment: @Gothdo What are examples of "unwanted variable side effects" and "unexpected behavior"?